# Computational resource intensivity of a simple window.onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've built a menu system that closes if you click off of the menu. To do this, i've used a simple window.onclick function.

The listener is only added to the window element if the menu is opened, but it is not removed from the window element when the menu is closed.

How computationally intensive is an window.onclick listener assuming that the function it runs ends up being `if(false){return};`?

Additionally, what are the best methods of checking the computational intensivity of script?

Comment: simple event callbacks typically consume less than a ms of ptime, which would allow 1000 clicks a second...

Answer (score 0):

The if statement would be constant time, but because you aren't removing them you are creating a memory leak. You could probably get away with this, but it's something you should try to avoid. I would recommend using khan academy to learn about time complexity of algorithms. The chrome console can be your best friend when trying to find memory leaks as well as determining how long it takes to run. I believe codeschool has a free course on the advanced features of the chrome console.